# Docker shows port 80 is mapped but requests do not reach the program in the container

Tags: docker, http, port, visual-studio-2019

Having problems accessing port 80 in a docker container from the host machine on windows 10 pro with visual studio 2019

I've set "httpPort:9876" in the launch settings file in VS launch settings and added EXPOSE 80 in the dockerfile.

docker ps shows the container has the following port mapping  0.0.0.0:9876->80/tcp when it runs.

I expect to load localhost:9876 and see the text "IF YOU SEE THIS MESSAGE IN YOUR BROWSER ITS WORKING"

However currently it gives the following error in the browser

localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

According to the debug information the request is not being received by the program inside the container. If i run the program without the container locally on the machine it works correctly. So it is something to do with the docker configuration.

I've created minimal code demo of the problem on git hub.

https://github.com/Rleahy/DockerBugDemo

Comment: You should be connecting to the exposed port. 80 in your case.

Comment: @JosefKorbel, that's not correct.  EXPOSE simply means that there is a service **inside** the container running on port 80.   OP is doing it correctly by trying to connect to localhost:9876.

Comment: @NickRundle no. Expose means which port is EXPOSED from the container.

Comment: @NickRundle "The EXPOSE instruction indicates the ports on which a container listens for connections." Source:https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#expose

Comment: I have just tried changing it to use port 80 inside and outside the container so they can't be the wrong way around, that also fails to send the request to the container.

Comment: @RangoBigins the git link is not working so hard to help further. Try to do this with pure docker outside of vscode. You should be familiar with the basic to consider the features helpful.

Comment: @JosefKorbel If you read the expanded [expose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) it says that "The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published."

Comment: Sure. You have to actually forward it with docker compose or `-p` flag. But it is indeed the supposed port to listen on. So the port you are using

Comment: I forgot to make the git repo public if you try again it should work now, and i understand that expose alone will not open the port, we have recently moved our development environment from  ubuntu-VScode to windows-VS2019 i'm not as familar with VS2019 which i think is likely part of the problem.

Comment: Do you know if there are addition settings that need configuring in VS 2019 currently i'm only changeing expose in the docker file and adding httpport to the launch settings is that be sufficient?

Comment: @RangoBigins checking. Are you running the container with docker compose?

Comment: No, its only a single container i'm running it through vs2019 debug launcher

Comment: What is the command vscode is using to launch it? I suspect you are running it using compose. And in your compose file you have port map as `'9000:9000'` which does not coresponds. Also I am not sure if you can use strings.

Comment: Hi yes sorry i experimented with the compose files but abandoned them as they didn't seem to help solve the problem i should have deleted them from the demo project. And i'm not using vscode any more we have switched to visual studio 2019 on windows, because we need the profiling tools which is when this problem occurred. If you open the solution file in vs2019 and run the docker debug profile that should replicate how i'm running it.

Comment: Also here is the docker command run -dt -v "C:\Users\roble\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "C:\Users\roble\source\repos\DockerBugDemo\BeliefEngine:/app" -v "C:\Users\roble\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -v "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -p 9876:80 --entrypoint tail beliefengine:dev -f /dev/null

Comment: That is generated automatically by VS2019 but it does seem to be trying to map the ports with -p 9876:80